# Adding TOS agreement checkbox with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We're using devise for our members.  We've added a tos_agreement field (boolean) to our member schema, and we added it to `views/devise/registrations/new.html.haml`.

In the Member model, we have a validation rule as follows:

```
validates_acceptance_of :tos_agreement, :allow_nil => false,
  :accept => true
```

It works fine - if you don't accept the TOS, you can't register.

However, the problem comes with editing your settings.  If you go to `/members/edit` you get the form where you can change your email address or password.  There's no field for the TOS agreement since this shouldn't be changeable at this point.  However, when you make a change (eg. change your password) and submit the form, it returns an error message that the TOS agreement can't be false.

How can we tell it never to attempt to modify the TOS agreement after the first registration?

**Edit:** so I think the fundamental problem is that we had :tos_agreement in our attr_accessible, which was a very bad idea now I think of it.  But if we remove it, how do we modify Devise to accept the parameter and do something with it even though it's not mass-assignable?

Comment: You also don't actually need to create a field in the database for these kinds of variables, rails will just create a virtual field for you. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance

Answer (score 23):

You can pass an :on => :create option to the validator so that it's only checked on signup:

```
validates_acceptance_of :tos_agreement, :allow_nil => false, :accept => true, :on => :create
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. It simply answers the original poster's question. and exactly what the OP originally asked for. if the circumstances changed later for the OP, that doesn't mean to credit that person who replied your exact question.