# Devise ToS Agreement Weird Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

So I have followed this thread to implement my ToS agreement functionality:
[Adding TOS agreement checkbox with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720634/adding-tos-agreement-checkbox-with-devise)

1. Migrated db with:

```
  def change
    add_column :users, :TosAgreement, :boolean
  end
```

2. Added this to the User model:

```
validates_acceptance_of :tos_agreement, allow_nil: false, accept: true, on: :create
```

3. Permitted param in registration controller:

```
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name, :tos_agreement])
  end
```

4. Added field to registrations/new form:

```
  = f.input :tos_agreement, as: :boolean,
         label: "I agree to #{link_to 'Terms of Service',
           terms_of_service_path, target: '_blank'}".html_safe
```

I am able to create a new user from within seeds.rb like this:

```
User.create!(email: 'test@email.com', password: 'test', password_confirmation: 'test', tos_agreement: true)
```

but when I try to sign up manually I get this error... have no idea why. Console output isn't helpful at all.
[image]

Here's the console output:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-01-13 10:17:57 +0200
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"test@test.com", "name"=>"mike", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "tos_agreement"=>"1"}, "g-recaptcha-response"=>"03AGdBq26wqQcP-VHYK5F8C4dJIPURhM2vMnH_qocWqyRDelbqDy3Kjxd0eykxlURjAn2GAKcy4CI25uSQcycs1MlXc-JfABuaxXgPafReov0EhLqaByu_Xmy0k2Ek3cRi-xN0olmODC5xEedR_PvnfYXF_UFIy-Pq4N_HI28jjDuhRemHzuCN2Xpo-w0BaqnMBJmYlI7bSZBZIXU19rVQYM7PRsLQRDzhlnddMlxEOzTlhG8vjbseT0CcFiwnfndL5QmRzXtEk0oDwsGSDcHasDPRoIoI24-vO9f33eXDFMg1aJq4WaEFno_xgOwmr2PUePMNriwHaUyQnqEOvs8JTEKhCaniomwLWsEhN-5YFrNloauDNdZ6F0XaIjpi6h_A2ViUOp6d8T47p9-c5rqKBHYetIwiXbR6QGj4UX990XfZ_v3nSTRLZjaqcRG_H3jwfrRgegs-uTBv", "commit"=>"Sign up"}
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
  TRANSACTION (0.8ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists? (2.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "test@test.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  TRANSACTION (0.7ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering devise/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 116)
  Rendered devise/registrations/new.html.haml within layouts/application (Duration: 20.7ms | Allocations: 14863)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/json-1.8.6/lib/json/common.rb:155: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated
  Rendered shared/_flash-message.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 41)
  Rendered shared/_search_bar.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 153)
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 1.3ms | Allocations: 483)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 184)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 36.4ms | Allocations: 23121)
Completed 200 OK in 447ms (Views: 37.1ms | ActiveRecord: 15.1ms | Allocations: 46662)
```

Comment: You should really name the column `:tos_agreement`. In ActiveRecord the convention is snakecase everything - columns, tables, indices etc. In this case you should actually be getting an error since ActiveRecord will generate the method names `TosAgreement`  and `TosAgreement=`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions

Comment: good point thanks, no idea how made it camel case here.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was having  `accept: true` in validations

```
validates_acceptance_of :tos_agreement, allow_nil: false, accept: true, on: :create
```

removing it from there solved the issue

```
validates_acceptance_of :tos_agreement, allow_nil: false, on: :create
```